# Do I need add db.close() after db.execSQL(sql)?

Tags: android

I customize a SQLiteOpenHelper by an example code, I think I should add db.close() after db.execSQL(sql), **right?**

```
public class RuleNumber extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

   private final static String DBName="smsforwardrulenumber.db";
   private final static String TableRuleNumber="rulenumber";

    public RuleNumber(Context context) {
        super(context, DBName, null, DBPublicPar.DBVersion);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql= "Create table " 
                + TableRuleNumber
                +" (numberID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
                +"ruleID INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"numberType INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +"number TEXT NOT NULL"
                + ");";     
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html):

> Releases a reference to the object, closing the object if the last reference was released.

If you don't interest to use the same instance (aka database connection) - **close it**.

But if you run multiple queries, you can close connection at the end.

Comment: Thanks! But I have browsed many example, these example havn't add db.close()  in the function public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db), why?

Comment: Generally examples are good only to see the flow but not "its right way". For that we have documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to close any connection that was not used any further in the activity to improve the performance of your app. Hence if you are not using the DB connection anymore then close it.